# Выборка many to many + несуществующие связи в pivot таблице

Tags: laravel, eloquent

У меня есть две модели, связанные pivot таблицей + поле value

```
class Field extends Model
{

    // RELATIONS

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'field_user', 'field_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('value');
    }
}
```

---

```
class User extends Model
{

     // RELATIONS


     public function mfields()
     {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Field', 'field_user', 'user_id', 'field_id')->withPivot('value');
     }
}
```

Вот мой код выборки:

```
$users = User::with(['fields' => function($query){
                $query->where('in_table', true);
         }])->get();
```

Вот выходные данные выборки для двух юзеров,
у первого есть связи, у другого нет связей:

```
 {
"users":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "fields":[
            {
                "id":2,
                "name":"first_name",
                "display_name":"Поле 1",
                "config":{"in_table":true,"table_link":false},
                "pivot":{
                    "user_id":1,
                    "field_id":2,
                    "value":"Значение поля 1"
                }
            },
            {
                "id":2,
                "name":"last_name",
                "display_name":"Поле 1",
                "config":{"in_table":true,"table_link":false},
                "created_at":"2017-02-20 14:26:01",
                "updated_at":"2017-02-20 16:16:36",
                "pivot":{
                    "user_id":1,
                    "field_id":2,
                    "value":"Значение поля 2"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "fields":[]
    }
]               
}
```

---

**Задача:**

Не хранить в pivot таблице записи с пустыми значениями value.

---

**Проблема:**

Поля выбираются только те, которые связаны в pivot таблице с юзерами.

А я бы хотел, чтобы выбирались и связанные и не связанные. У тех полей, у которых нет связи в pivot таблице, была заполненность без pivot данных.

**PS:**

У меня задача вывести пользователей в таблице с его полями и те поля у которых нету связей хочу выводить пустыми.

Comment: Что-то не понятно, зачем у вас в связующей таблицы лежат элементы без связей ? и кстати есть такой метод `wherePivot('active',1)` - если вам нужно проверять условие в связующей таблице

Comment: Да, верно, я могу назначить связи  и это бы решило мою проблему. Но если в связующей таблице будет очень много пустых связей (мне value интересен) как это отразится на скорости выборки? Пользователей будет много, полей будет много, а вот заполненное value в pivot может и не быть (а если value нет, то и в связи нету необходимости).

Comment: Значит нужно делать выборку из модели Field, если нужны все поля. В чем проблема?

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов я вывожу таблицу с юзерами с их полями. Выборку начинаю с юзеров. Сначала получаю список пользователей, а потом получаю у каждого пользователя поля.

Обновил свой вопрос. Добавил пример, что у меня получается на выходе.

Comment: Я понимаю. Но если коилчество полей постоянно и одинаково у каждого юзера, то твой подход не имеет смысла. Ты понимаешь, что для каждого поля ты получаешь дополнительный запрос на выборку?

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов сейчас не стоит вопрос о количестве доп. запросов. Главное - не иметь лишних записей в pivot. Если производить выборку из модели Fields, то получится тоже самое, но в другой последовательности. У меня будут все поля, но юзеров (несвязанных) не будет. Или я чего-то не понимаю. Можно ли пример того, о чем вы говорите.

Answer (score 0):

Задачу решил не самым изящным способом, но на данное время подойдет.

```
// выбрал колонки (из полей) для таблицы и конвертировал в массив
$columns = Field::where('config->in_table', true)->get()->toArray();
// отсортировал колонки ...

// выбрал список юзеров с полями для таблицы и конвертировал в массив
$users = User::with(['fields' => function($query){
            $query->where('config->in_table', true);
     }])->get()->toArray();

// дальше длинная обработка массива с юзерами, в котором:
// - у массива колонок делаю индексами - id колонки (поля) 
// - массив колонок сравнивается с массивом полей юзеров по id, и при недостающих последних, добавляются + добавляются доп поля (например, value='')
// - также сортирую массивы полей у юзеров по аналогии с колонками (чтобы поля попали в свои колонки)
```

В конечном итоге получились годные данные для показа в таблице.